# Selected state of tab bar icon in IOS 7

Tags: ios7, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I'm having fun learning to build my first iPhone app and wonder if someone would kindly point me in the right direction.

I have basically added in custom icons for my tab bar (IOS 7). Now I want to add in a custom selected state icon for each of these. How would I do this?

Thanks

Shell

Comment: you want to add icons on top bar or downbar ? You can use UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: As of Xcode 6, you can do this by default in Interface Builder. No need for any custom solution.

Answer (score 19):

As of Xcode 6, you can do this by default in Interface Builder. No need for any custom subclasses or categories as before.

Comment: The use of user defined runtime attributes is neat.

Comment: Heck, that's an awesome solution.

Comment: Why isn't this answer selected? This is just awesome!

Comment: Removed my answer because it is no longer needed in Xcode 6

Answer (score 4):

On iOS7 you should set [`selectedImage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarItem/selectedImage)

```
tabBarItem.selectedImage = selectedImage;
tabBarItem.image = unselectedImage;
```

Keep in mind that `selectedImage` is not available in iOS6.
Use [`– setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarItem_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBarItem/setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage:) if you have to support iOS6.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the swift solution based on @MrAlek's solution, create a custom UITabBarItem

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class YourTabBarItem: UITabBarItem {

    @IBInspectable var selectedImageName:String!{
        didSet{
            selectedImage = UIImage(named: selectedImageName)
        }
    }
}
```

and in interface builder, change the class of the tab bar item and you will see the Selected Image Name attribute, just specify your selected image name there. I reckon @IBInspectable is using the runtime attribute.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

See my more complete answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20007782/1755055

Often your tab will have a Navigation Controller stack, so you will need the following

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

...

    [self.navigationController.tabBarItem setSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MySelectedIcon.png"]];

}
```

If you only have one view controller in the tab without the `UINavigationController` wrapper, you would use

```
[self.tabBarItem setSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MySelectedIcon.png"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like below and its solve the image issue in iOS7:

```
[self.navigationController.tabBarItem setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"MySelectedIcon.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can user sub method to init a tabBarItem.

```
-(instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title image:(UIImage *)image selectedImage:(UIImage *)selectedImage
```