# iOS 8 custom tab bar controller in UIStoryboard

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard, ios8

I am trying to create custom tab bar controller in UIStoryboard in iOS 8 with swift (objective-c also okay). So, I plan to use this code.

```
let item0: UITabBarItem = UITabBarController().tabBar.items[0] as UITabBarItem
item0.setFinishedSelectedImage(selectedImage0, withFinishedUnselectedImage: unselectedImage0)
```

However, problem is that `setFinishedSelectedImage` is no longer supported and I see this error. How shall I implement?

**APIs deprecated as of iOS 7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift**

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage: deprecated in iOS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563193/uitabbaritem-setfinishedselectedimage-deprecated-in-ios7)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have Xcode 6 to test this so CODE NOT TESTED but I expect something similar to this in Swift:

```
var selectedImage0 : UIImage = UIImage(named:"selectedImage0.png").imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
self.navigationController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = selectedImage0
```

To get the first `tabBarItem` I would expect something similar to the follow but again CODE NOT TESTED:

```
// self.yourTabBarController is an IBOutlet to your UITabBar controller
let tabBar = self.yourTabBarController.tabBar 

// UITabBar Items are an array in order (0 is the first item)
let tabItems = tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem]
tabItems[0].title = "First"
tabItems[0].selectedImage = selectedImage0
tabItems[1].title = "Second"
tabItems[1].selectedImage = selectedImage1
/*
etc...
*/
```